# Why does forEach not work with new Array?

Tags: javascript

Consider the following example:

```js
let A = new Array(3);
A.forEach((_, index) => {
  A[index] = 1;
});
console.log(A);
```

Why does it return `[undefined undefined undefined]`? I was expecting it to return `[1 1 1]`.

Comment: Array methods only iterate over own-properties on the array. `new Array` results in an array without (array-indexed) own-properties. Try `A.hasOwnProperty(1)`, you'll see it gives you `false`. Since sparse arrays like these are really weird and unintuitive, best to never use `new Array` unless it's immediately followed by something that populates the whole array, like `.fill`